# Next page does not open. Problem with pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, axios

I need to make a pagination in my task, but it is not working.

I made two buttons to which I attached the "click" event and I registered a property in the "data". When I click on the buttons, the property changes and is written to the link and in the same way changes the current 10 posts to the following.

But for some reason it does not work as it should work. Can someone please explain what my mistake is and if you can suggest some articles on the subject of "pagination".

This is my html:

```
  <button type="button" @click="counter -=1" class="prev">Prev</button>
  <div class="counter">{{ counter }}</div>
  <button type="button" @click="counter +=1" class="next">Next</button>
```

This is my Vue:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter: 1,
      zero: 0,
      posts: [],
      createTitle: '',
      createBody: '',
      visiblePostID: ''

    };
  },

  created () {
    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=10').then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data;
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `created` method is called only when the component is created. To make the `GET` request everytime the counter increase or decrease use `watches` [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

Your example will become:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter: 1,
      zero: 0,
      posts: [],
      createTitle: '',
      createBody: '',
      visiblePostID: '',
    }
  },
  watch: {
      counter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          this.getData()
      }
  }
  created(){
      this.getData()
   },
   methods: {
      getData() {
          axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=10`).then(response => {
              this.posts = response.data
          })
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did as you said, but it did not work. Counter is changing but the posts remain the same as they were.

Comment: I tried again but it did not work. Here is my GitHub https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/VueAxios/tree/pagination/src

Comment: It doesn't work because you confuse single quote with apostrofe. When you type the URL you are using single quote with `${variable}`. When you are using this syntax (`${variable}`) you should use apostrofe instead of single quote. I edited my answear and sorry. I didn't noticed this at first.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for your time)))

Comment: No problem. Take care when you are using string interpolation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a watcher for your counter that fires a load method. This way every time your counter changes you'll load in the correct posts for the page in your paginated results.

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
        return{
            counter: 1,
            ...
        }
    },

    created(){
        this.loadPosts()
    },

    watch: {
        counter(newVal, oldVal){
            this.loadPosts()
        }
    },

    methods: {
        loadPosts(){
            axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=10')
                .then(response => {
                    this.posts = response.data
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-vue/vue-events-build-a-counter
I don't know vue, but looks like you need a function to load new data